# communicate with serial port via as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, serial-port

i have an application made with flash (AS3), the application is pretty simple , the are a few images that is shown , you have to choose if the image shown is true or false like a quizz, to choose the right answer you have to tap on a material buzzer that send an asci code to me (electronic solution) and i fetch the code and if the answer is true or false it show the result ,
probleme is : 
we want to change color of buzzer if the answer is good or not (red / green), to do that i have to send the good answer to the buzzer via serial port to chenge the buzzer LED color corresponding to that answer...
is there any solution with AS3 ??

Answer (score 1):

Use socket-proxy-serial like [serproxy](http://www.lspace.nildram.co.uk/freeware.html) and call it using [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html).